# Where do I find JavaScript malware?

Tags: malware, javascript

I am looking  for JavaScript malware. I need it just for local tests on my computer for a project I am working on. Are there any Internet resources where I could find this?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody suggested browsing for some pron which should be sure way to catch a few js malware examples.

Comment: @Cthulhu Its flawed technique when you are interested in just one type of malware ;)

Comment: @Cthulhu I read that [religious sites are worse than porn sites](http://blogs.wsj.com/tech-europe/2012/04/30/religious-sites-are-worst-for-malware-report-finds/) a while ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking for malware to study and understand how it works [metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/) is great. The framework is open source so you can study how it works.

You can [search](http://www.rapid7.com/db/search?q=Javascript&t=m) the metasploit database.

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for when you say "JavaScript Malware" but if you mean JavaScript that could compromise users who view a site [CVE-2012-3993](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/browser/firefox_proto_crmfrequest) looks pretty cool.

If your looking for JavaScript that if injected to a site could do nasty things [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) is a good resource.

I also quite like Troy Hunt's [Intentionally Vulnerable Site](http://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/) it gives you a good playground where you can break things and he has some good training on what not to do.

Comment: I want to develop a tool that allows me to detect JS malware when I visit a given website. So i am also interested in websites that perform drive by download attack

Answer (score 4):

Try [BeEF](http://beefproject.com) framework, It is specifically useful for a wide range of web browsers and has tested methodologies. Once the main javascript file is loaded in the client browser(Through cross site or any other means), an attacker can perform full control of the client system depending upon the available browser specific exploits.